# Why is the output -33 for this code snippet

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, code-snippets

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=32;
    printf("%d\n", ~a);  //line 2
    return 0;
}

o/p = -33
```

Actually in the original snippet line 2 was

```
 printf("%x\n", ~a);  //line 2
```

I solved it like

```
32 in hex is 20.
0000 0000 0010 0000
now tilde operator complements it
1111 1111 1101 1111 = ffdf.
```

I am confused how to solve it when I have

```
printf("%d\n", ~a);  //line 2 i.e %d NOT %x.
```

Comment: -1: printing an unsigned int using `%d` casts it to a signed integer.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @Jongware: Is that really downvote-worthy? The question itself is just fine: complete code, expected result, actual result, and reasoning for the expected result. Relatively spot on, actually.

Comment: It shows a basic misunderstanding of signed vs. unsigned numbers and how you should inspect them. A similar question on hex vs decimal "representation" got way more downvotes.

Comment: What did you *want* it to print with `%d`? -33 is the correct value. Also: you got ffdf and not ffffffdf... you have 16-bit `int`s?!

Comment: "It shows a basic misunderstanding of signed vs. unsigned numbers and how you should inspect them."  Seems like the right thing to do is correct the misunderstanding then, no?

Comment: @Andrey The thing is if I convert 32 into binary i.e 0011 0010 and invert the bits I will not get -33. That's what baffling me.

Comment: @user3058364 What everybody's trying to tell you is that you *do* get -33 by inverting the bits of 32. That's how two's complement works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your C implementation, as in most modern implementations of any programming language, signed integers are represented with [two’s complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

In two’s complement, the high bit indicates a negative number, and the values are encoded as in these samples:

```
Bits  Decimal
0…011 +3
0…010 +2
0…001 +1
0…000  0
1…111 -1
1…110 -2
1…101 -3
```

Thus, if the usual (unsigned) binary value for the bits is *n* and the high bit is zero, the represented value is +*n*. However, if the high bit is one, then the represented value is *n*-2<sup>*w*</sup>, where *w* is the width (the number of bits in the format).

So, in an unsigned 32-bit format, 32 one bits would normally be 4,294,967,295. In a two’s complement 32-bit format, 32 one bits is 4,294,967,295 - 2<sup>32</sup> = -1.

In your case, the bits you have are 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101 1111. In unsigned 32-bit format, that is 4,294,967,263. In two’s complement, it is 4,294,967,263 - 2<sup>32</sup> = -33.

Answer (score 1):

You should print out `unsigned` integers with the `%u` specifier:

```
unsigned int a = 32;
printf("%u\n", ~a);
```

Printing it out with `%d` treats it as a signed integer.

You see it as a negative number because the sign bit is set from 0 to 1 through the binary negation.

Printing it out as a hex number doesn't interpret the sign bit, so you see the same result in both cases.

Comment: Hi if it is   int a=32, still it prints -33

Comment: @user3058364: leave it `unsigned int` and print it with `%u`, rather than with `%d`.

Comment: That is fine. But why does it print -33 when I use int a = 32 and NOT unsigned int a= 32 ?

Comment: @user3058364: you should either use `unsigned int` with a `%u` specifier, or an `int` with a `%d` specifier. It gets trickier otherwise.

Comment: I want to use  int with %d specifier. I have replaced  unsigned int to int in the original question.

Comment: @user3058364: In that case it is entirely normal to have a negative value printed out after the negation.

Answer (score 0):

Most computers use two's complement representation for negative numbers.  See here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Data_Representation_and_Practical_Exercise/Fundamentals_of_Data_Representation/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Can you fill us in a bit more?